# How to select element from the sibling's child element javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, ejs

I want to select a form by clicking a button that is a child of the form sibling parent.. i know it's confusing.

```
<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center task">
      <span class="task"><%= task.taskDescription %></span>
      (this-form)=> <form action="/edit" method="POST" class="hidden edit-form">
        <input type="text" name="taskDescription" />
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%-task._id%>" />
      </form>
      <div class="btns">
        (this-btn)=> <button class="edit">Edit</button>
        <form action="/delete" method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" class="edit" name="id" value="<%-task._id%>" />
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the form directly using any unique selector.  An id might be best, but in the example given, you could use `document.querySelector('.edit-form')`.

If there's multiple similar elements and you want to be sure to get the one with the common parent from the button's onclick handler:

```
function onclick() {
  const form = this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.edit-form');
  // do what you want with form here
}
```

What it does is:

1. start from `this` (the button clicked)
2. Go up to the parent of the DOM element twice (first to `<div class="btns">` then to the `<li ...>` element)
3. From there we select the `<form class="edit-form ..." ...>` element.

Comment: That's exactly what i wanted. thanks, u r a life saver :)